# How to add Foreign Key and Cascade properties with Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I want to implement this MySQL query with Sequelize for my express.js Model.

```
CREATE TABLE `Serivce_Area` (
  `service_area_id` int auto_increment primary key,
  `service_id` int not null,
  `area_id` int not null,  
  FOREIGN KEY (service_id) REFERENCES Service_Credential(service_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES Area_Details(area_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here I have two other tables named Service_Credential and Area_Details with two primary keys naming service_id and area_id. This is how far I've done.

```
const serviceArea = sequelize.define('Serivce_Area', {
    service_area_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    service_id:{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    area_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
});
```

But I'm having trouble with adding the Foreign Key and Cascade properties. I have checked the documentation. But still I'm not sure how to do it. Besides, some stackoverflow answers contains `belongsTo` and `hasMany` properties which I'm not sure how to use in this situation. Please help me with this.

Comment: You would need to create all of your models first if you plan to use those in your code as well. I would suggest you have a look at the following documentation as it will explain how the models relate and how the SQL is generated: https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#foreign-keys
If you're still stuck, I can provide a basic example from your code

Comment: If you want to apply the cascade on update and delete, you would do something like `cerviceCredential.belongsTo(serviceArea, { onUpdate: 'CASCADE', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })`. This would be dependent on your model relationships

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me with this solution. And it worked.

```
    service_area_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    service_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Service_Credential',
        key: 'service_id'
      }
    },
    area_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Area_Details',
        key: 'area_id'
      }
    }
```